# Array of String values to get inserted into TextArea field

Tags: apex, visualforce, string

I am having a list of contact names in an array of String. I am trying to insert those names into a Text area field while inserting the record, but getting an error. 
How can I implement this?

Is there any other way I can save those names in any different field type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a string join. For instance if you want the values to be new line delimited, you would do:

```
someRecord.TextAreaField__c = String.join(names, '\n');
```

You can of course change the delimiter to any character you wish.

Comment: So I have this: `String[] myList = new String[]{};` .....SomeCode.....`myList.add(c.Name);` .....SomeCode......`someRecord.TextAreaField__c = myList.join('\n');`.........
I am getting an error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void join(String) from the type List<String>` What's wrong I did? I appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: @Austin Fixed the syntax in my post.

Comment: You are the rockstar at the SFSE.